# Add to wishlist using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, wishlist

How to add product to wishlist with a single button click without page redirect and refresh using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You need to  create a custom module for it.I have followed below mentioned tutorial to crate ajax base add to wish list and it;s working fine in my magento 1.9.1 and magento 1.9.3

[click here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/27/magento-ajax-based-add-product-to-wishlist-and-compare-products/)  for complete code.

Answer (score 1):

you can add, remove, update wishlist by ajax: http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/customer-experience/guest-wishlist-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Please install below ajax to cart extension which

https://github.com/hwguyguy/magento-ajax-wishlist - I hope it will works for you.